# Option Button properties dialog not showing

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

My co-worker is able to insert a radio button (`Option Button`) using the `Developer` tab.

The `Design Mode` and `Properties` options are both "live" (not greyed out).

However, when she clicks on the `Properties` option, the properties pop up box does not show.  Is there a setting we need to change?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in "Design Mode" first.

Then right-click the option button and select Properties.

The "properties button" in the ribbon requires that the correct control have focus. Using right-click ensures the focus is always on the correct control.

[image: EXAMPLE]